# The present simple in "We leave London at 10.00 next Tuesday"

Tags: present-tense, future-constructions

If someone says

> **We leave** London at 10.00 next Tuesday  and **arrive** in Paris at 13.00. **We spend** two hours in Paris and **leave** again at 15.00..

What do here present tenses mean? Do they mean like:

> *we have to leave London at 10.00 next Tuesday and we have to arrive in Paris at... because It has been timetabled by someone else(not by us). and It is a fixed arrangement.*

Comment: As an aside, although most linguists call this a present tense (because its central purpose is to indicate present time), there are some who would call it a "nonpast" tense instead.

Answer (score 3):

The simple present (as future form) can be used to express

- plans and scheduled events like timetables
- events in the near future
- future facts

You example falls flatly in the first category.

Comment: In other words, yes.  The arrangements are fixed, the timetable exists, the events are scheduled.  These are present-tense facts, even though they are facts about future events.

Comment: Actually the present can also be used when you give instructions and when you describe a state of affairs in the present.