# "expires" vs "ends" in this specific case

Tags: word-choice, tense

> My contract expires at the end of May.
>
> My contract ends at the end of May.

Which one between `expires` and `ends` is more suitable here?
Another question plz: which tense is more suitable for the sentence, the present or the future?

Comment: Both are fine. Historically, [***expires*** has always been more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+contract+expires%2Chis+contract+ends&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20contract%20expires%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20contract%20ends%3B%2Cc0), but you might like to note that ***ends*** is gaining ground. My guess is the simpler version will probably dominate eventually, so I suggest you take the easy route and learn to *use* the simpler and more obviously literal usage right from the get-go (but *recognise* the other).

Comment: (For the *tense* issue, have a look at [Meaning of the present tense in this context?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42711/))

Comment: I suppose that by simpler version you mean "ends" (?). The thing I find a bit odd with the usage of "ends" here is the other "end" that folllows the first one.

Comment: Because *contract **ends*** is a verb, whereas ***end** of May* is a noun, native speakers wouldn't normally register anything odd there. Obviously the two words are "etymologically connected", but people don't think about that while speaking - they're effectively just a couple of homophones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are perfectly acceptable in this context.  "Expires" can sound a little more *official* since it's has a narrower definition than "end", but it's not a big deal.

It's also fine to use either the present or future tense.  Both are common.

> My contract expires at the end of May.
>
> My contract will expire at the end of May.

Another possibility:

> My contract is up at the end of May.
>
> My contract will be up at the end of May.